# Django 1.5 - Time field

Tags: django

I'm having a problem with a django time field.

My model:

```
class IpCameraAlert(models.Model):
    ipCamera = models.ForeignKey(IpCamera, verbose_name='Zone')
    start = models.TimeField()
    end = models.TimeField()
    email_to = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Email to')
    sms_to = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='SMS to')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', editable=False)
```

If I do the following:

```
        timenow = datetime.datetime.time(datetime.datetime.now())
        alerts = IpCameraAlert.objects.filter(ipCamera=camera, start__lte=timenow, end__gte=timenow)
```

I always get the response:

```
ValueError: Can't encode datetime.time(13, 10, 50, 251016)
```

Or similar depending on the time. It used to work in 1.4, but for some reason it's now not working.. Any ideas?

Comment: Could it be an issue related to the new timezone support in Django 1.5? You can either try to use `django.utils.timezone.now` instead of `datetime.datetime.now()` or desactivate timezone support with `USE_TZ = False` in your settings.

Comment: I think it's not a problem with the model. The model looks okay and the query Ben is making looks good too. What are you doing with `alerts` variable?

Comment: use DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

Answer (score 0):

In your `alerts` line of code:

```
alerts = IpCameraAlert.objects.filter(ipCamera=camera, start__lte=timenow, end__gte=timenow)
```

Django is trying to filter with `start__lte` but Django 1.5+ uses `datetime.datetime` format for filtering for dates, but the format you have defined is `datetime.time`.  So it is best to change the definition of `timenow` to the following:

```
timenow = datetime.datetime.now()
```

Or you can use the Django timezone utility:

```
from django.utils import timezone
timenow = timezone.now()
```

Then your `alerts` line of code should be able to properly filter for the time.